# Python regex to exclude email pattern but include @string pattern

Tags: python, regex

Consider I have the string of the following:

```
string = "Hello, please send message to @david, @nick, @jack, but do not send message to any email address like json1234@google.com or nelson.tan@yahoo.com, thanks!"
matches = re.findall("\@\w+", string)
print(macthes)

#return ['@david', '@nick', '@jack', '@google', '@yahoo']
```

However, I would only want to return `['@david', '@nick', '@jack']`

How can I exclude the pattern for email address so that it only return me the name tag using @. Thanks.

Comment: Use `r'\B@\w+'` or `r'(?<!\S)@\w+'`

Comment: Wow, it works amazing, may I know how it is working?

Comment: You should visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493483/3832970) below.

Answer (score 2):

Since emails contain a word char before `@` you may use `\B`:

```
r'\B@\w+'
```

The `\B` *here* matches at the start of the string or if there is a non-word char before `@` (punctuation other than `_` or whitespace). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Ugmi8/1).

If you know the strings you need to extract are after whitespace/start of string use

```
r'(?<!\S)@\w+'
```

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is no whitespace immediately to the left of the current location. Hence, `@\w+` only matches at the start of the string or after a whitespace. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Ugmi8/2).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ik5FRD):

```
import re    
s = 'Hello, please send message to @david, @nick, @jack, but do not send message to any email address like json1234@google.com or nelson.tan@yahoo.com, thanks!'
print( re.findall(r'\B@\w+', s) )
# => ['@david', '@nick', '@jack']
print( re.findall(r'(?<!\S)@\w+', s) )
# => ['@david', '@nick', '@jack']
```